# How to Extract pattern substring from text in C sharp?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a long text and want to extract MODEID from this text. MODE ID starts with MODE+30 digits ('MODE123456789012345678901234567890'). How to extract this string from the text column in C sharp code.

Here is my code snippet from the Script task which is failing in the SSIS package can anyone help me here.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^MODE[0-9]{34}$");
Match match = regex.Match(Row.Audit);
if (match.Success)
{  
  Row.MODEID = match.Value;
}
else 
{ 
  Row.MODEID = 'MISSINGMODEID";
}
```

where Row.MODEID is text column.

Row.Audit sample column looks like

' Audit gives multiple key-value pairs and MODE ID in this text. MODEID is :MODE123456789012345678901234567890and key-value pairs are xyz:1233, abc:234'

I want to extract alphanumeric string which start with 'MODE' Word.

Comment: If there are always 30 digits in the MODE ID, then the Regex should have {30}, not {35}. If there is text before or after the the MODE ID, then you do not want the ^ or $ characters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I want to extract 30digits along with MODE word.

Answer (score 0):

remove ^ and $, this mean start and end of line, not the case here.